# randomize functions

Tags: c++

```
  void main()
 {

  randomize();
  char city[][10]={"DEL","CHN","KOL","BOM","BNG"};
  int i,fly;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
   fly=random(2)+1;
   cout<<city[fly]<<":";
  }
 }
```

What is the output of the following code snippet?

Comment: Um, what is `randomize` and `random`? And how shall we predict a random number? **And `main` returns an `int`!**

Comment: Why don't you try compile and run it?

Comment: I have not mentioned the header file stdlib.h

Comment: the answer is changing each time when i compile the program

Comment: Well. do mention it - and use the functions srand() and rand(), which are part of the C++ Standard.

Comment: "the answer is changing each time when i compile the program". Does it change each time you *run* the program? Why do you suppose that might be?

Comment: randomize function is used for generating random numbers 
but if i'm asked to write the output of this program what will i write

Comment: @anurag Please try to understand what we are saying - you are using non-standard functions, and we cannot predict how your non-standard random number generator, on an unknown platform, will behave.

Comment: But what is the big deal. Ask your question, what is the thing that you don't understand. what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *same* output every time you run a program using random number generators, you want to seed the generator with the same value every time. For example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std:

int main() {
   srand( 42 );  // generator always seeded with same value
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      cout << rand() << endl;
   }
}
```

always produces the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

random(2) is either 0 or 1
Therefore fly = random(2) + 1 is either 1 or 2
city[fly] is either "CHN" or "KOL" 
since loop repeats thrice, the possible answers are

- CHN:CHN:CHN
- CHN:CHN:KOL
- CHN:KOL:CHN
- CHN:KOL:KOL
- KOL:CHN:CHN
- KOL:CHN:KOL
- KOL:KOL:CHN
- KOL:KOL:KOL